# auto time delay css banners

Tags: jquery, css, banner

There are four images , and each images has to be border effect(css) by using time delay sequentially. For example:

**O** O
O O

after 5seconds

O **O**
O O

after 5seconds

O O 
**O** O

Does anyone know how to make it ?

Comment: You should tell us what you've tried so far, show some code, tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use CSS then, given the HTML below, this is possible (though a little clunky):

```
<div id="timer">
    <div class="interval"></div>
    <div class="interval"></div>
    <div class="interval"></div>
    <div class="interval"></div>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
@-moz-keyframes loading {
    0%, 24% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    25%, 100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes loading {
    0%, 24% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    25%, 100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes loading {
    0%, 24% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    25%, 100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    0%, 24% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    25%, 100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@keyframes loading {
    0%, 24% { /* stops the gradual fading-out */
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    25%, 100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

#timer .interval {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-animation: loading 20s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: loading 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: loading 20s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loading 20s linear infinite;
    animation: loading 20s linear infinite;
}

#timer .interval:nth-child(1) {
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    animation-delay: 0;
}

#timer .interval:nth-child(2) {
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

#timer .interval:nth-child(3) {
    -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -o-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

#timer .interval:nth-child(4) {
    -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
    -o-animation-delay: 15s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-delay: 15s;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LYnTb/1/).

Or, using CSS transitions but using JavaScript, in this case jQuery (for simplicity), to trigger the next step, rather than manually using, and setting, the `animation-delay` with CSS:

```
function transNext(currentEl, transitionClass) {
    if (!currentEl) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        transitionClass = transitionClass || 'interval';
        var cur = $(currentEl),
            nxt = cur.next().length ? cur.next() : cur.prevAll(':last');
        cur.removeClass(transitionClass);
        nxt.addClass(transitionClass);

    }
}

$('#timer').on('mozAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd animationEnd', function(e) {
    transNext(e.target, 'interval');
});​
```

And the modified CSS:

```
@-moz-keyframes loading {
    0%, 99% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes loading {
    0%, 99% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes loading {
    0%, 99% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    0%, 99% {
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@keyframes loading {
    0%, 99% { /* stops the gradual fading-out */
        border-color: #f00;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

#timer div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#timer .interval {
    -moz-animation: loading 5s linear 1;
    -ms-animation: loading 5s linear 1;
    -o-animation: loading 5s linear 1;
    -webkit-animation: loading 5s linear 1;
    animation: loading 5s linear 1;
}
​    ​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LYnTb/2/).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the [''setInterval''](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) JavaScript function. Look at [this JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvZFA/5/) for an example how it could work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="marker"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.marker {
    background: #999;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.marked {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

​
**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(function() {
    // Set border around first element
    jQuery('.container .marker:first').addClass('marked');

    // Start interval with 5 second steps
    var iv = setInterval(function() {
        // Executes every 5 seconds

        // Is there a next element?
        if (jQuery('.marker.marked').next('.marker').length == 1) {
            jQuery('.marker.marked')   // actual marked element
                .removeClass('marked') // remove border
                .next('.marker')       // go to next element
                .addClass('marked');   // add border
        } else {
            // No next element? Start again with first element
            jQuery('.marker.marked').removeClass('marked');
            jQuery('.container .marker:first').addClass('marked');
        }
    }, 5000);
});​
```

It is not clear from your question if you want to do one run from left to right or if it has to start again on the left after the last image in the sequence. My example stops after last div. You would have to replace the DIV elements with your image elements. They only have to have the class ''marker'' attribute.

**EDIT**: The updated fiddle/code above cycles through the elements and repeats again with the first element.

Comment: oh forgot this question... how to make it  not to stop on last div ?  it has to be repeat activing all time...?

Comment: I updated the code to repeat the cycle again and again. If this is the answer you wanted, please accept it as the right answer. Thx :)